# How can i skip blank lines when reading from a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file

How can I skip blank lines when reading from a file in c++?
the set up is: I have a text file with a set of 50 questions each one followed by four possible answers. I am using a 2d array to store all of this: questions[50][5]

so the text file is structured like this:

1 line length questions

answer a

answer b

answer c

answer d

1 line length questions

answer a

answer b

answer c

answer d

and so on..

there is no gap between the question or any of the answers, but between each group of question and 4 answers, there is an unknown amount of blank lines.

I'm using a loop to input the question and for answers into my array for each set of questions, but how can I skip the unknown amount of blank lines for each set of questions? here is my code

```
    //reading in the questions
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {


    while(getline(qFileIn,test)) //seeing if its empty
    {
            if(test.empty())
                    continue;
            if(!(test.empty()))
                    break;
    }
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {

                    getline(qFileIn,questions[i][j]);
            }

    }
```

I'm really struggling with trying to skip the blank lines somewhere within those two for loops, and i'd much appreciate some help.
Thanks!!!

Comment: The part of your code that tries to skip a line is good, but you only actually perform it once every six lines...

Comment: Try asking a rubber duck, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) for help

Comment: But when I use getline to skip a line, i'm still just reading it and if it isn't a blank line then theres no way for me to read that same line again and save that line in the questions array

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe qFileIn.ignore(256, '\n'); it skips empty lines.